# How would I redirect existing pathname followed by non-existing pathname to pathname?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I use React and React with Switch and Route from react-router-dom.

When a user goes to [www.mysite.com/nonExistingPathName](http://www.mysite.com/nonExistingPathName) it is redirected to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) using

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />
<Route path="/otherpage" component={otherpage} />
<Redirect to="/" />
```

How would I go about to redirect the user to [www.mysite.com/otherpage/nonExistingPathName](http://www.mysite.com/otherpage/nonExistingPathName) to
[www.mysite.com/otherpage](http://www.mysite.com/otherpage) ?

Adding "exact" to "otherpage" redirects the user to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) which is less desirable. Without "exact" they go to [www.mysite.com/otherpage](http://www.mysite.com/otherpage) but the url still contains/otherpage/nonExistingPathName which just looks weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

How is the user arriving at [www.mysite.com/otherpage/nonExistingPathName](http://www.mysite.com/otherpage/nonExistingPathName)?  Do you have existing links to that page?  In general I think it's fine to have the non-exact match and keep the URL.

#### Two Route Components

If we want to redirect traffic to [www.mysite.com/otherpage](http://www.mysite.com/otherpage), we can combine an exact and a non-exact match.  The exact match renders the component.  The non-exact match (which must come after) catches all other matching traffic to this path and redirects it to the correct path.

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/otherpage" component={OtherPage} />
      <Route path="/otherpage">
        <Redirect to="/otherpage" />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

#### UrlEnforcingRoute

We can extract that logic into a reusable component that you can use in place of `Route`.

```
const UrlEnforcingRoute = ({ path, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route {...props} exact path={path} />
      <Route path={path}>
        <Redirect to={path} />
      </Route>
    </>
  );
};
```

(Typescript users: this component is type `React.FC<Omit<RouteProps, 'exact'> & { path: string })>`)

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <UrlEnforcingRoute path="/otherpage" component={OtherPage} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```